# Scroll the page below the fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of certain button i was scrolling particular div to top of the page. This was working fine till my header was not fixed.After I made the header fixed some portion of the div is hidden by the header. Is there any way to make sure the page loads just below the header.

I tried below but it didn't worked out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop(5);
});
```

Comment: just add padding-top or margin-top to the content...

Comment: margin-top leaves a gap between 2 divs. I dont want that. 
My page consists of multiple divs in form of container of graphs.

Comment: then add padding-top to the topmost content, it'll be nice if you can add a fiddle.

Comment: Can you get header's height using `var headerHeight = $("[data-role=header]").height();` and use `$(document).scrollTop(headerHeight);`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).scrollTop($("#targetDiv").offset().top - $("#header").height());
```

will scroll to the desired position.

And if you want to scroll smoothly on a button click:

```
$("#targetButton").click(function() {
  $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#targetDiv").offset().top - $("#header").height() });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a css property called `scroll-margin-top`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-scroll-margin-top-property/).

So I referenced the `div` element by Id and gave it `scroll-margin-top`.

```
#manifesto {
  scroll-margin-top: 200px;
}
```

When I navigate to the specific `div`, it gives it more space below the fixed header.